# Visual Studio publish error code 0x80070005 -- Bootstrap license

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Out of nowhere, after multiple successful Publishes, Visual Studio 2022 gives me an error when I try to publish to Azure.  It's looking on my D: disk for a Bootstrap license.  There is no D: disk.

I hit this a couple weeks, not with Publish but just building.  I solved it eventually by deleting my bin folder.  That's not working today.

Looking around, others have hit something similar, but did not seem to be my situation.

2021-12-01: no clues out there as to how to solve?

Here is log output:

Unable to perform the operation ("Create File")  for the specified directory ("D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Identity\lib\bootstrap\LICENSE"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
The error code was 0x80070005.
Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Identity\lib\bootstrap\LICENSE' is denied.
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, Nullable`1 fileLength)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
Publish failed to deploy.

```
2>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 18):

I'm having the same exact issue, looks like the issue is caused by VS 2022. I think it is taking a file that has no extension named License and mistaking it for a folder. I was able to fix the issue by deleting the License file and the folder that was created on my web server by VS 2022 on deploy.

Comment: Same solution for me, I deleted the License folder on the server using FileZilla.

Comment: Also worked for me, fixed using FileZilla.

However, it's not VS 2022, it's targeting .NET 6. With VS 2022 everything worked fine when I targeted .NET 5, but when I changed the target to .NET 6, it broke with this Bootstrap LICENSE error.

Comment: @TonyIsaac: I think you're correct. .NET 6 uses Bootstrap 5, whereas .NET 5 used Bootstrap 4. Consequently there's a change in the location/content of the Bootstrap files that get included by the Identity package.

Comment: Thanks,
@TonyIsaac
@GaryMcGill

The problem was that in .Net 5 there was a folder named `Identity/Bootstrap/LICENSE` and inside it a `LICENSE` file, and after migration to .Net 6 the bootstrap folder structure changed. The `LICENSE` folder was removed and the `LICENSE` file was moved to the path `Identity/Bootstrap/`. The error was that the deploy service was trying to create the file `LICENSE` at the exact location beside the old `LICENSE` folder!

Answer (score 14):

I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Open the Azure Portal
2. Open the App Service page
3. Open the Console blade
4. In the console, navigate to D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot
5. Remove the Identity folder with **rmdir /s /q Identity**.

Comment: Helpful commands to resolve the issue. I only needed to remove the problematic LINCESE path (folder and file). Navigated to D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Identity\lib\bootstrap and executed rmdir /s /q LICENSE

Comment: We had the exact same access denied error for the LICENSE file. It turns out that upgrading to .NET 6 changes the location of the file, and the deployment fails. Using the Console in Azure App Service i navigated to `wwwroot\Identity\lib\bootstrap` and deleted the folder LICENSE (containing the file LICENSE). The next deployment then succeeded.

Comment: Frode Evansen's solution worked for me as well.

Comment: Instead of rmdir /s /q Identity I run: "rm -r Identity"
It worked!

Answer (score 4):

I was having similar issues regarding that file when deploying to azure app services.

I was able to fix the issue by ensuring that "Remove additional files at destination" was enabled.

Azure Portal:

[image: Azure Portal]

Comment: I thought issue was fixed.  I'd configured "delete old files", publish worked (at which point MS support exited), thought I was OK, then realized later it was running old cold, not code I was trying to upload.  I had to scour all publishing parameters.  One of the ones that surprised me, buried in the csproj file XML had "publish" set to false; I had to change it to true.  Then I got hit by access to my key vault file. I hope I'm past all that.

Answer (score 4):

We're publishing to a folder and what fixed it for us was setting "Delete existing files" to `true` in the Publish Dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Got it fixed thanks to MS support.  Somehow server folder wwwroot structure had been corrupted.

Comment: not in azure. running on windows server. renamed the identity folder. re-released. new identity folder created ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in an Azure DevOps release pipeline. I solved the issue by reverting the release pipeline to an earlier state.

The issue started after I had experimented with WebDeploy instead of ZipDeploy. However, WebDeploy didn't suit my needs, so I changed the release pipeline to ZipDeploy using the Devops release pipeline editor (the GUI you probably use most of the time). After this, the Zip Deployments started to fail, and the error was
`Error: The target file "C:\home\site\wwwroot\...\bootstrap\LICENSE" is a directory, not a file.`.

After reverting the release pipeline to a state previous to the WebDeploy experimentations, the pipeline started working properly again. This is what changed in the revert: [image]

On the left was the pipeline definition after changing back to ZipDeploy from the pipeline editor UI (`"DeploymentType"` is `"zipDeploy"`). However, for some reason, `UseWebDeploy` was left to `true` from the WebDeploy experiment. I assume this caused some incorrect logic in the deployment service.

Reverting the edits in the pipeline changed this (on the right). [Here](https://dailydotnettips.com/revert-azure-devops-pipeline-changes/) is one guide to reverting DevOps pipelines.